# Sort Pandas dataframe according to list of column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this-

```
d = {'class': [0, 1,1,0,1,0], 'A': [0,4,8,1,0,0],'B':[4,1,0,0,3,1],'Z':[0,9,3,1,4,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    A   B   Z   class
0   0   4   0   0
1   4   1   9   1
2   8   0   3   1
3   1   0   1   0
4   0   3   4   1
5   0   1   7   0
```

and I have a list like this-`['Z','B','class','A']`

Now I want to sort my pandas dataframe according to the list of column names

therefore the new dataframe would have the columns names-

```
Z  B  class A
```

Comment: You can just do `df[['Z','B','class','A']]` this question has been asked before

Answer (score 3):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
L = ['Z','B','class','A']
df = df.reindex(columns=L)
```

Or select by subset:

```
df = df[L]
```